# MacBook Pro Catalina - Input Monitoring

Tags: macos, catalina, system-settings, driver, privacy

I hope someone can help me.

I was updating my driver for my XP-Pen drawing tablet. Part of the instructions included adding the app and the driver to Input Monitoring. However, the + and - sign at the bottom of that screen is not available which means I cannot manually add anything there. It also does not allow drag and drop.

Is this standard on Catalina? Is there a setting I'm missing. I have Admin permissions - it's my computer.

Thank you all ahead of time!

Comment: I assume you have tried using the software and it did **not** ask you for permission to monitor inputs. Because this is the usual way things behave. The app request a permission, then you can grant the permission.

Comment: Does [this answer about Wacom drivers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387333/18101) help you?